# An expression attribute name used in the document path is not defined; attribute name: #buyer

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using reserve DynamoDB keywords live value,users, name. I have create entry in DynamoDB with

```
{
   "id":1
  "poc_name": "ABC"
}
```

I want to update exiting records with

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "poc_name": "ABC",
    "buyer": {
        "value": "id1",
        "label": "Test"
    }
}
```

I am using reserve keyword "value". When I try to update the record I am getting error:

> An expression attribute name used in the document path is not defined; attribute name: #buyer

Update is not working because buyer map does not exist in DynamoDB. That's why I am getting document path is not found. I using following code snippet to handle the reserve keyword, It will generate the following updateValues, updateExpression, expression_attributes_names

```
updateValues: {':poc_name': ABC, ':buyer_value': 'id1', ':buyer_label': 'Test'}
updateExpression: ['set ','poc_name = :poc_name,','#buyer.#value = :buyer_value,', 'buyer.label = :buyer_label,']
expression_attributes_names: {'#demand_poc_action': 'demand_poc_action', '#value': 'value', '#buyer': 'buyer'}
```

Code snippet:

```
for key, value in dictData.items():
        if key in RESERVER_DDB_KEYWORDS or (
            "." in key and key.split(".")[1] in RESERVER_DDB_KEYWORDS
        ):
            key1 = key.replace(".", ".#")
            updateExpression.append(f"#{key1} = :{key.replace('.', '_')},")
            updateValues[f":{key.replace('.', '_')}"] = value
            if "." in key:
                expression_attributes_names[f"#{key.split('.')[0]}"] = key.split(".")[0]
                expression_attributes_names[f"#{key.split('.')[1]}"] = key.split(".")[1]
            else:
                expression_attributes_names[f"#{key}"] = key
        else:
            updateExpression.append(f"{key} = :{key.replace('.', '_')},")
            updateValues[f":{key.replace('.', '_')}"] = value
    
UpdateExpression="".join(updateExpression)[:-1],
ExpressionAttributeValues=updateValues,
ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW",
ExpressionAttributeNames=expression_attributes_names,
```

The problem is that if buyer already exist in the DynamoDB then I will be able to update buyer record, however I am not able to update record for buyer which doesn't have buyer In DynamoDB then I am getting document path error. So my approach is that I will create the entry of buyer every time I do the update. However I am not able to fix above code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are trying to update nested properties of top level property `buyer`, which does not exist yet (OR is not of map type)

So before running this update you have to ensure that the top level attribute `buyer` already exists.

Or you can just catch the exception if it is thrown, and perform an another update creating the `buyer` attribute, like shown below:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

table = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1').Table('test1')

try:
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            'pk': '1'
        },
        UpdateExpression="SET #buyer.#value = :val1, #buyer.#label = :val2",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#label': 'label',
            '#value': 'value',
            '#buyer': 'buyer',
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':val1': 'id1',
            ':val2': 'Test'
        }
    )
except ClientError as e:
       if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ValidationException':
            # Creating new top level attribute `buyer` (with nested props)
            # if the previous query failed
            response = table.update_item(
                Key={
                    'pk': '1'
                },
                UpdateExpression="set #buyer = :val1",
                ExpressionAttributeNames={
                    '#buyer': 'buyer'
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':val1': {
                        'value': 'id1',
                        'label': 'Test'
                    }
                }
            )
        else:
            raise
```

An alternative approach is to simple set `buyer` to an empty map when creating the item:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "poc_name": "ABC",
   "buyer": {}
}
```

This would allow you to update nested attributes as `buyer` would exist.

Comment: Thanks for Answering as you see that I am writing for general case, same update operation will handle the different records, It is possible to add map object in try block instead of exception, where I am creating updateValues. ExpressionAttributeValues and ExpressionAttributeNames